# Testing methods that depend on an essentially random instance variable

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I'm working on a Blackjack game. My Game object contains a deck object that gets shuffled after the deck reaches a certain level of penetration. Many of my methods depend on this deck object. I don't see any reason for the deck object to be accessible through setter methods. I'm having trouble testing the methods on my Game class, since they depend on the order of the deck, which is random.

For instance, I have the deal_hand method.

```
def deal_hand(player)
    reset_deck if @deck.size < 2
    player.hands.push(Hand.new(*@deck.pop(2)))
end
```

How should I test a method like this? I was thinking I could just manually create a Deck object that gets used in the @deck instance variable. Unfortunately, I can't set the instance variable, and I don't really want to add a setter, since there's no reason for that to be "settable" except to test. Should I monkey patch the class from my test-file and add a setter?

As an aside--I mostly write scripts--I decided I needed to start writing tests after this project got out of hand. Is there any canonical resource for "testing patterns?"

edit:

I am using MiniTest, which supports stubbing/mocking. Though as far as I can tell, it only lets you set expected return values for method calls on the mock object. If I made a Mock deck, the actual deck object also depends on an internal array. None of the code that calls the deck accesses the array directly.

Comment: how's @deck set in the first place?

Comment: are you open to a refactoring suggestion that might make this more easily testable?  If not that's okay :-)

Comment: Yes, I would be. @deck is an array of Card objects that has been randomized with shuffle!. It gets set when Game.new is called.

Comment: I realized I should probably change the method to accept a deck parameter as well. That way I'm not implicitly relying on the state of the @deck instance variable. Is that the refactoring suggestion you were going to make?

Comment: I'd agree with the answer below to move to a mock/stub approach instead of what you asked specifically about.  I'd also refactor the deal_hand method as it's doing a lot.  Player should probably know about how to add a hand, to its set of hands rather than having Game doing it.  Game should pass player a hand and tell it to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a mock library. RSpec comes built with one, but I dislike it, so I'll show you what it might look like with [Surrogate](http://github.com/JoshCheek/surrogate), the one I wrote:

```
class Deck
  def pop(n)  end
  def reset() end
  def size()  end
end

class Game
  def initialize(deck)
    @deck = deck
  end

  def deal_hand(player)
    reset_deck if @deck.size < 2
    player.hands.push(Hand.new(*@deck.pop(2)))
  end

  def reset_deck
    @deck.reset
  end
end

Hand = Struct.new :card1, :card2

class Player
  def hands
    @hands ||= []
  end
end

require 'surrogate/rspec'
class MockDeck
  Surrogate.endow self
  define(:reset)
  define(:pop)  { |n| n.times.to_a }
  define(:size) { 1 }
end

describe Game, 'deal_hand' do
  let(:deck)   { MockDeck.new }
  let(:player) { Player.new }
  let(:game)   { Game.new deck }

  it 'resets the deck if there are less than 2 cards' do
    deck.will_have_size 2 # set the return value of deck.size
    game.deal_hand player
    deck.was_not told_to :reset # assert what happened to the deck

    deck.will_have_size 1
    game.deal_hand player
    deck.was told_to :reset
  end

  it 'deals the top 2 cards to the player' do
    deck.will_pop [:card1, :card2]
    game.deal_hand player
    deck.was told_to(:pop).with(2)
    player.hands.last.should == Hand.new(:card1, :card2)
  end
end

describe Deck do
  it 'is substitutable for the mock' do
    # because we use the mock in tests
    # we want to make sure its interface matches the real deck
    Deck.should substitute_for MockDeck
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [mocha](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/)?

That would allow you to stub or mock the Deck to ensure that it has the expected cards for your test runs.

Answer (score 1):

In your test use the method instance_variable_set, which is a ruby method on object.

So I am assuming your method is in the Game class, so you if you're setting up something like

```
@test_deck = something_that_sets_up_state_of_test_deck

@game = Game.new
@game.instance_variable_set(:deck, @test_deck
```

That will set your instance variable within Game, without the need for attr_accessible or getters and setters being explicitly built.

Comment: This is the right answer to your question.  However, all that being said, I think that you may want to take a look at testing styles that are more based around mocks and stubs.  Mock out the deck object and stub the methods on the mock to return whatever is needed so you can truly test the deal_hand method in isolation.  Thinking about how to do this will also help you decouple your logic - your method as is has to know about a lot of stuff to do its job - chained methods like you have can be a code smell that you have too coupling between your objects.